# How to disable QOS in router setting?

Tags: internet-connection, qos, adsl-router

I try to disable QOS configuration in router setting and do such as below

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**but Qos is Enabled**

My Isp tell me that my router configured to 8Mbs but my internet service is 16Mbs.
How can I disable it?

Comment: The QoS you can control is *within* your network exiting *to* the WAN (Wide Area Network - the Internet). You are unlikely to be able to control whether your ISP has set up QoS on your incoming internet connection.

Comment: @ Mokubai  but we can set limit of speed of client's internet connection by Qos configuration.

Comment: *client* yes. As in *within your own network*, the QoS on the page where you see it "enabled" has nothing to do with client machines. It is the connection between your modem and the ISP modem.